# How to yank a CtrlP match result in vim

Tags: vim, ctrlp

Is it possible to copy a search result form the `ctrlP` match window? With `<s-tab>` one can focus the match window but it doesn't seem posible to yank from there.

I often have to search for files that I need in my scripts, but I only remember their names vaguely. So I use `ctrlP` to find the file. No I'd like to paste the matching file name to my script. I cannot find anything like this in the documentation of `ctrlP`!

[image]

For example in this case I want to copy the path the cursor is on (in the match window at the bottom) to a register and then paste it into the above window...

Comment: Please give with an example.

Comment: Interesting. Maybe it would be possible to somehow exploit `g:ctrlp_open_func` and grab the match to a register instead of opening it, but it's just a guess...

Answer (score 0):

*(Notice: This is not an advertisement!)*

I don't use CtrlP so I have no idea to do it with CtrlP.

Now I use [LeaderF](https://github.com/Yggdroot/LeaderF) for fuzzy search and I think it may solve your problem.

With LeaderF, once the search window is open, you can press `Tab` to switch to normal mode. And then you may use, for example, `yy` to yank a filename and paste it to the above window.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I has the same question. And follow ~guessimtoolate suggestion. I come up with this custom function for CtrlP.
Press *Ctrl-t* over the file will append it's filename at the cursor.

```
function! YankFilenameFunc(action, line)
  if a:action =~ '^[t]$' 
    " Get the filename
    let filename = fnameescape(fnamemodify(a:line, ':t'))
    " Close CtrlP
    call ctrlp#exit()
    exec "normal a". filename ."\<Esc>"
  else
    " Use CtrlP's default file opening function
    call call('ctrlp#acceptfile', [a:action, a:line])
  endif
endfunction
let g:ctrlp_open_func = { 'files': 'YankFilenameFunc' }
```